# how to populate a list box with the file content dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to populate a html list box (select tag) with the content of file (i.e each line of the file should become a single option in the list box (select element)).

suppose i have a file say `"load_lines.txt"` containing

```
s1.txt
s2.txt
s3.txt
s4.txt
s5.txt
```

there is a html form

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>List box Loading</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="frm1" name="frm1" action="" method="GET">

      <select id="lb" name="lb" size="5">
      </select><br /><br />

      <input type="button" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="OK" />

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

when the form is loaded it should populate the list box (select element) with the contents of the file `"load_lines.txt"`.

can anyone tell how to do this using javascript?. please give the javascript code.

Comment: I would suggest the use of PHP, or ASP; seeing how it's fairly impossible to read text files in pure JavaScript speaking cross-browser wise...

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client browser, and the file would be located where the web page is on on the server - you will have to use some kind of server-side implementation

Comment: [This might help](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=l_8MkZJevpf), although it's a HTML5 feature and not well supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to get the job done. Hope this helps.

```
<form id="frm1" name="frm1" action="" method="GET">
    <select id="lb" name="lb" size="5"></select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="OK" />
</form>
<script>
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open('GET', 'load_lines.txt');
        client.onreadystatechange = function() {
                t = client.response 
                t = t.split('\n');
                var listbox;
                for(i=0;i<t.length;i++){
                        listbox +='<option value="'+i+'">'+t[i]+'</option>';
                }
                document.getElementById('lb').innerHTML=listbox;
        }
        client.send();
</script>
```

Comment: Does not work due "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."